# Junit test error - DictionaryServiceTest.testAddDictionary:65 expected:<com.dictionary.model.Dictionary@6c26e588> but was:<null>

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, junit

**Test class**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DictionaryServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    private DictionaryService dictionaryService;

    @MockBean
    private DictionaryRepo dictionaryRepo;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        System.out.println("Before method in dictionary service");
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
        System.out.println("After method in dictionary service ");
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddDictionary() {

        //Set<DictionaryValue> dictionaryValue = new HashSet<>();


        Dictionary dictionary = new Dictionary();
        dictionary.setId(1);
        dictionary.setDictionaryName("Test Dictionary");
        dictionary.setDictionaryDescription("Running first test case of dictionary");
        dictionary.setDictionaryKey("123456789");
        dictionary.setStatus("2");
        dictionary.setCreatedOn(new Date());
        dictionary.setUpdatedOn(new Date());
        //dictionary.setDictionaryValues(dictionaryValue);



        Mockito.when(dictionaryRepo.save(dictionary)).thenReturn(dictionary);

        assertThat(dictionaryService.addDictionary(dictionary)).isEqualTo(dictionary);


    }
```

**Model class**

```
@Entity
public class Dictionary {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    private int id;
    private String dictionaryName;
    private String dictionaryDescription;
    private String dictionaryKey;
    private String status;
    private Date createdOn;
    private Date updatedOn;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dictionary", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<DictionaryValue> dictionaryValues; 

    }
```

When I am executing test class for this model I am getting above error for this model. I don't know why Can anyone help me out?

Service class and Repository interface is working perfectly fine they are working as expected.

..............................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you have setup the expectation that the save method on the dictionaryRepo will be called with the dictionary object but it is being called with null.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mock the service as well as its dependency: that doesn't make sense.

So, assuming the service is autowired with the repository in your `ApplicationContext`, simply autowire in the *real* service into your test class like the following.

```
@Autowired
private DictionaryService dictionaryService;
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it!

Comment: Great. Glad it works for you. Feel free to _accept_ my answer if it solves your issue. ;-)

Comment: Hey Sam, Now when I am trying to run below test case it is showing error. no value present. Can you please explain?

Comment: @Test
public void testgetDictionaryListById() {  
DictionaryValue dictionaryValue = new DictionaryValue();
dictionaryValue.setId(1);
dictionaryValue.setValueName("Test Dictionary Value");
dictionaryValue.setValueKey("12345678");
dictionaryValue.setUpdatedOn(new Date()); Mockito.when(dictionaryValueRepo.findById(1).get()).thenReturn(dictionaryValue);assertThat(dictionaryService.getDictionaryListById(1)).isEqualTo(dictionaryValue);

Comment: What does `dictionaryValueRepo.findById(...)` return? An `Optional<DictionaryValue>`?

Comment: no I used .get() so it is not asking me to make Optional<DictionaryValue> , It is returning me proper records

Comment: You have to _mock_ the call to `findById()`, not the call to `get()` since `get()` is not on a mocked object. So, without access to your code, I can only assume the following will work: `when(dictionaryValueRepo.findById(1)).thenReturn(Optional.of(dictionaryValue));`

Comment: By the way, you really should have asked this in a separate _question_ on Stack Overflow.